# shinjs::show() not showing element after shinyjs::hide()

Tags: r, shiny, hide, show, shinyjs

I have a shiny dashboard where I'm trying to use action buttons to select through what to show instead of the menu tabs.  I have it built so that when you click the action button assigned to one specific fluid row it will hide the other tabs, but I can't seem to get it to bring the fluid row back.  I'm using shinyjs `show` and `hide` functions.

this is the code I have in my ui

```
    dashboardBody(
     tags$head(
       tags$link(
         rel = "stylesheet",
         type = "text/css",
         href = "datainstate_style.css")
     ),
     useShinyjs(),
     introjsUI(),

 # MAIN BODY ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

     fluidRow(
       column(
         width = 12,
           bsButton("VsOpponent", 
                    label = "Vs Opponent", 
                    icon = icon("users"), 
                    style = "success"),
           bsButton("trendsinperformance", 
                    label = "Trends", 
                    icon = icon("digital-tachograph"), 
                    style = "success"),
           bsButton("lineupsandchampions", 
                    label = "Lineups and Champions", 
                    icon = icon("child"), 
                    style = "success")
       )
    ),

    fluidRow(
      div( id = "VsOpponent_panel",
        column(
          width = 12,
          gt_output("opponents_table")
        ),
        column(
          width = 12,
          plotOutput("radar_plot")
        ),
        column(
          width = 12,
          plotOutput("gold_plot")
        )
      )
     ),
 fluidRow(
   div( id = "trendsinperformance_panel",
     column(
       width = 12,
       plotOutput("gold")
     )
   )
 ),

 fluidRow(
   div( id = "lineupsandchampions_panel",
     column(
       width = 12,
       textOutput("test")
     )
   )
 )
   
  )
```

And then the code in my server that corresponds to this is below

```
  ## Determine which panel to show
  observeEvent("", {
    show("VsOpponent_panel")
    hide("lineupsandchampions_panel")
    hide("trendsinperformance_panel")
  }, once = TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$VsOpponent, {
    show("VsOpponent_panel")
    hide("lineupsandchampions_panel")
    hide("trendsinperformance_panel")
  })
  observeEvent(input$trendsinperformance, {
    show("trendsinperformance_panel")
    hide("lineupsandchampions_panel")
    hide("VsOpponent_panel")
  })
  observeEvent(input$lineupsandchampions, {
    show("lineupsandchampions_panel")
    hide("trendsinperformance_panel")
    hide("VsOpponent_panel")
  })
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the buttons seem to work for me as expected, try to `hide` the `divs` first then `show` the other ones

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 4,
            bsButton("VsOpponent", 
                     label = "Vs Opponent", 
                     icon = icon("users"), 
                     style = "success"),
            bsButton("trendsinperformance", 
                     label = "Trends", 
                     icon = icon("digital-tachograph"), 
                     style = "success"),
            bsButton("lineupsandchampions", 
                     label = "Lineups and Champions", 
                     icon = icon("child"), 
                     style = "success")
        )
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
        div(id = "VsOpponent_panel",
             column(
                 width = 4,
                 plotOutput("p1")
             ),
             column(
                 width = 4,
                 plotOutput("p2")
             ),
             column(
                 width = 4,
                 plotOutput("p3")
             )
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(
        div( id = "trendsinperformance_panel",
             column(
                 width = 4,
                 plotOutput("p4")
             )
        )
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
        div( id = "lineupsandchampions_panel",
             column(
                 width = 4,
                 plotOutput("p5")
             )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$p1 <- renderPlot({plot(runif(10),main = "Plot1")})
    output$p2 <- renderPlot({plot(runif(10),main = "Plot2")})
    output$p3 <- renderPlot({plot(runif(10),main = "Plot3")})
    output$p4 <- renderPlot({plot(runif(10),main = "Plot4")})
    output$p5 <- renderPlot({plot(runif(10),main = "Plot5")})

    
    ## Determine which panel to show
    observeEvent("", {
        hide("lineupsandchampions_panel")
        hide("trendsinperformance_panel")
        show("VsOpponent_panel")
    }, once = TRUE)
    
    observeEvent(input$VsOpponent, {
        hide("lineupsandchampions_panel")
        hide("trendsinperformance_panel")
        show("VsOpponent_panel")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$trendsinperformance, {
        hide("lineupsandchampions_panel")
        hide("VsOpponent_panel")
        show("trendsinperformance_panel")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$lineupsandchampions, {
        hide("trendsinperformance_panel")
        hide("VsOpponent_panel")
        show("lineupsandchampions_panel")
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! for whatever reason just moving show to the end didn't fix it but moving those observe events sections to be after rendering the plots like you have yours set up made it work.  Thanks!!